# R - could not find function "cld"

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply these codes for 
https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_08.html

my problem

```
library(multcompView)
> library(lsmeans)
> lsmeans = lsmeans::lsmeans ### Uses the lsmeans function
> leastsquare = lsmeans(model,
+                       "B_exp_type",
+                       adjust="tukey")
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions

   > cld(leastsquare,
    +     alpha=.05, 
    +     Letters=letters)
    Error in cld(leastsquare, alpha = 0.05, Letters = letters) : 
      could not find function "cld"
```

how to fix this could not find function "cld" error ??

Comment: That looks like an old guide you are working off and It looks like cld was removed from lsmeans. When I loaded lsmeans i got the message "*The 'lsmeans' package is now basically a front end for 'emmeans'*"; emmeans has a CLD function

Comment: Use `multcomp::cld`. The generic is in the **multcomp** package, and the method for it is in **emmeans**. Or consider something like `pwpp()` instead, as I really think CLDs are misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the `multcomp` package.

Best advert for namespacing I've seen for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of that page.

There are many minor updates I need to do to that site.  One is updating all calls to the `lsmeans` package to the `emmeans` package.  Unfortunately, I used `lsmeans` like 100 times, so it's a lot of little updates.

As mentioned, you can call `cld` from `multcomp`.  The following page lists options for that call regarding an `emmeans` object:

[rdrr.io/cran/emmeans/man/CLD.emmGrid.html](https://rdrr.io/cran/emmeans/man/CLD.emmGrid.html)

The following code gives an example:

```
library(emmeans)

warp.lm = lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

marginal = emmeans(warp.lm, ~ tension:wool)

pwpp(marginal)

library(multcomp)

cld(marginal, reversed=FALSE, alpha=0.05, details=FALSE, 
    adjust="sidak", level=0.95, Letters=letters)
```

Comment: The package lsmeans still exists and it is just a front-end to emmeans. The lsmeans function itself is in the emmeans package. So all your stuff will run if you load either package. However, the generic for `cld` is in the **multcomp** package, so you either need to load that package or reference it via `multcomp::cld(... etc ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@Keith McNulty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239392/r-could-not-find-function-cld/62239432#62239432): Besides installing and loading the {multcomp} package, **you must also have the {multcompView} package installed** to use `multcomp::cld()`.

Here is a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) of when {multcompView} is not installed:

```r
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)
#> Error in library(multcompView): there is no package called 'multcompView'

mod <- lm(weight ~ group, data = PlantGrowth)
emm <- emmeans(mod, "group")
cld(emm, Letters = letters)
#> Error in .requireNS("multcompView", "The 'multcompView' package must be installed to use CLD methods"): The 'multcompView' package must be installed to use CLD methods
```

And here is one where it is installed:

```r
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)

mod <- lm(weight ~ group, data = PlantGrowth)
emm <- emmeans(mod, "group")
cld(emm, Letters = letters)
#>  group emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  trt1    4.66 0.197 27     4.26     5.07  a    
#>  ctrl    5.03 0.197 27     4.63     5.44  ab   
#>  trt2    5.53 0.197 27     5.12     5.93   b
```

Also, [here](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/dsfair_quarto/summaryarticles/compactletterdisplay.html) is a short chapter I wrote on the compact letter display.